# Pointer to struct with offset

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly

I have a pointer to `struct`, its `0xB7CD98`. And the offset to some float value `0x540`. How to get this value. All its in C++ and assembler. Another thing is that this its code from my dll injected to exe.

```
        float buffer ;

    _asm {
        MOV EAX, [0xB7CD98]+0x540
        MOV buffer, EAX
    }
```

But it isn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Assembly for that?

```
float* pBuffer = (float*)(0xB7CD98 + 0x540)

printf("%f", *pBuffer);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, that adress '0xB7CD98' is pointer to some game struct I find it in game documentation. Additional information,  when i use program like cheat engine and type Manual Adress there are something like `pointer` i typing pointer adress and offset, then it gives me value.

Answer (score 0):

Disassembly of your code :

```
0FB310E7  mov         eax,0B7D2D8h;
0FB310EC  mov         dword ptr [buffer],eax
//It just fill 'buffer' with 0xB7CD98+0x540
```

What you really want is this :

```
DWORD basePtr = *(DWORD*)0xB7CD98;
float someVal = *(float*)(basePtr + 0x540);
```

Or, if you wish to obtain a permanent pointer to this value :

```
typedef struct _XStruct
    {
        BYTE fill_0[0x540];
        float Value;
    }*PXStruct;
//...

    PXStruct basePtr = (PXStruct)0xB7CD98;
//0F0745E7  mov         dword ptr [basePtr],0B7CD98h  
    float buffer = basePtr->Value;
//0F0745EE  mov         eax,dword ptr [basePtr]  
//0F0745F1  fld         dword ptr [eax+540h]  
//0F0745F7  fstp        dword ptr [buffer]
```